# Show timestamp and not date in chart - SQL

Tags: vb.net, charts

I'm working on a data handling page for a customer.

I've made a chart that shows data from my SQL server.
On my x-axis I have a date but the whole column contains also a timestamp e.g. "08/01/2019 14:34", but is not visible.

As seen on the linked picture below, how do I format the x-axis value to only show the time, or the whole value from the dbo, if possible?

[image: Picture of chart with the date only]

Do I have to format the size of the chart on the screen, if so, how do I do that? I've tried looking for an option in the chart settings.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```vb
Private Sub dgvSiteChart() 'Load data from dbo
    DateandTimeString24H = "'" & Date.Now.Year & "-" & Date.Now.Month & "-" & Date.Now.Day & " 00:00:00.000'" & " And " & "'" & Date.Now.Year & "-" & Date.Now.Month & "-" & Date.Now.Day & " 23:59:59.000'"
    SQLCon = New SqlConnection
    SQLCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & System.Net.Dns.GetHostName() & "\KVMSQL;Initial Catalog=MHA;User ID=#####;Password =######"
    Dim READER As SqlDataReader

    Try
        SQLCon.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "SELECT DateAndTime,Tagindex,Val FROM dbo.FT WHERE tagindex=0 and DateAndTime between " & DateandTimeString24H & "ORDER BY DateAndTime"
        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
        READER = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader
        While READER.Read
            chrtReportMchn.Series("LOG").Points.AddXY(READER("DateAndTime"), READER("Val"))
        End While
        SQLCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        SQLCon.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Date and time format is `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm(24H)`.

UPDATE: 10/1-19

I've figured it out, with the help of @Markus with his comment.
The code is edited with `FORMAT(CAST(DateAndTime as time), 'hh\:mm\ ')` put in front of the `DateAndTime`.

```vb
Try
    SQLCon.Open()
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "SELECT FORMAT(CAST(DateAndTime as time), 'hh\:mm\ ') DateAndTime,Tagindex,Val FROM dbo.FT WHERE tagindex=0 and DateAndTime between " & DateandTimeString24H & "ORDER BY DateAndTime"
    SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
    READER = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader
    While READER.Read
```

Comment: when you only want to show the time, why not cast the datetime column in the select query

Comment: like so 
FORMAT(CAST(DateAndTime as time), N'hh\:mm\:ss') [time]

Comment: Hi Markus. Thanks for the reply. I'm pretty new at this, so I can't seem to work out where I should put the FORMAT(CAST(DateAndTime as time), N'hh\:mm\:ss') [time]  line in my code.
I've tried it in the Query but it reponded with a blank chart, and an ERROR occurs when I try it out in SQL Server mngt studio

Comment: I've figured it out. See post update. Thanks Markus.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Dispose` all database-related objects (connections, commands, readers). It is better to use `Using` for that instead of doing it manually in `Finally`.
You have to use parameters instead of [string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683). That way you also don't lose the last second of the day (between 23:59:59 and 00:00:00 of the next day).
You can use a dot in the connection string to represent the local computer.
You don't need to return `TagIndex` if you are not using it.
You can format the date on the client.

```
Private Sub dgvSiteChart()
    Try
        Using SQLCon = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\KVMSQL;Initial Catalog=MHA;User ID=#####;Password =######")
            SQLCon.Open()
            Using SQLCmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT DateAndTime,Val FROM dbo.FT WHERE tagindex=0 and DateAndTime >= @from_inclusive and DateAndTime < @to_exclusive ORDER BY DateAndTime", SQLCon)
                Dim captured_date = DateTime.Today ' Because it may change if calling this around midnight

                SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@from_inclusive", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = captured_date
                SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@to_exclusive", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = captured_date.AddDays(1)

                Using READER = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While READER.Read()
                        chrtReportMchn.Series("LOG").Points.AddXY(CType(READER("DateAndTime"), Date).ToShortTimeString(), READER("Val"))
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```